# The meaning of end-to-end QoS in network

Tags: cisco, qos, network-core

When saying (end-to-end QoS) in network, what do we really mean by that?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

QoS is a very large and complex subject that encompasses everything from classifying and marking packets, to performing some sort of action (shaping, policing, queuing, etc.) based on the classification/marking.

End-to-end QoS involves classifying and marking packets at the source and having comprehensive and consistent QoS policies of how the various classifications/markings are treated from the packet source to the packet destination.